# Failed to load libraries: [netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32, netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora, netty_tcnative_arm_32, netty_tcnative]

Tags: java, netty, raspberry-pi3, google-cloud-speech, grpc-java

I am trying to run a java application using jar on raspberry pi modal 3. I am unable to resolve this issue. Could someone kindly suggest how can I make this work on the raspberry pi?

In pom, I have included google-cloud-speech dependency, 0.56.0-beta; and spring-boot-starter-web dependency.

Error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32, netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora, netty_tcnative_arm_32, netty_tcnative]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:93) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:430) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:97) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:242) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:171) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:120) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DefaultNettyTransportCreationParamsFilterFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:558) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DefaultNettyTransportCreationParamsFilterFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:551) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:489) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:337) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
         com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:118) [google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at de.pfiva.speech.text.client.service.GoogleCloudService.getSpeechToText(GoogleCloudService.java:27) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at de.pfiva.speech.text.client.SpeechTextClientController.getspeechToText(SpeechTextClientController.java:47) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ....
    ....
    ....
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:205) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
            ... 75 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32.so
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
            ... 76 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32 in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
                ... 76 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32 in java.library.path
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:263)
                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:255)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:233)
                    ... 77 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:205) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
            ... 75 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora.so
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
            ... 76 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
                ... 76 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora in java.library.path
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:263)
                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:255)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:233)
                    ... 77 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_arm_32
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:205) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
            ... 75 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_arm_32.so
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
            ... 76 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_arm_32 in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
                ... 76 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_arm_32 in java.library.path
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:263)
                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:255)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:233)
                    ... 77 common frames omitted
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:205) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
            ... 75 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libio_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative.so
            at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
            ... 76 common frames omitted
            Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
                at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
                ... 76 common frames omitted
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative in java.library.path
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
                    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:263)
                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:255)
                    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:233)
                    ... 77 common frames omitted

    2018-11-03 17:19:02.682  INFO 11639 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts    : Conscrypt not found (this may be normal)
    2018-11-03 17:19:02.690  INFO 11639 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] i.g.n.s.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts    : Jetty ALPN unavailable (this may be normal)

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.JettyTlsUtil.isJettyAlpnConfigured(JettyTlsUtil.java:64) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
 io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:171) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:120) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DefaultNettyTransportCreationParamsFilterFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:558) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DefaultNettyTransportCreationParamsFilterFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:551) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:489) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:337) [grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:405) [grpc-core-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:206) [gax-grpc-1.29.0.jar!/:1.29.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:157) [gax-grpc-1.29.0.jar!/:1.29.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:149) [gax-grpc-1.29.0.jar!/:1.29.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:151) [gax-1.29.0.jar!/:1.29.0]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.stub.GrpcSpeechStub.create(GrpcSpeechStub.java:94) [google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.stub.SpeechStubSettings.createStub(SpeechStubSettings.java:126) [google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.<init>(SpeechClient.java:144) [google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:126) [google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:118) [google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at de.pfiva.speech.text.client.service.GoogleCloudService.getSpeechToText(GoogleCloudService.java:27) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at de.pfiva.speech.text.client.SpeechTextClientController.getspeechToText(SpeechTextClientController.java:47) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ...
    ...
    ...
    2018-11-03 17:19:02.730 ERROR 11639 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available] with root cause

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:256) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:171) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:120) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DefaultNettyTransportCreationParamsFilterFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:558) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DefaultNettyTransportCreationParamsFilterFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:551) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:489) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:337) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:405) ~[grpc-core-1.13.1.jar!/:1.13.1]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:206) ~[gax-grpc-1.29.0.jar!/:1.29.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:157) ~[gax-grpc-1.29.0.jar!/:1.29.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:149) ~[gax-grpc-1.29.0.jar!/:1.29.0]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:151) ~[gax-1.29.0.jar!/:1.29.0]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.stub.GrpcSpeechStub.create(GrpcSpeechStub.java:94) ~[google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.stub.SpeechStubSettings.createStub(SpeechStubSettings.java:126) ~[google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.<init>(SpeechClient.java:144) ~[google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:126) ~[google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:118) ~[google-cloud-speech-0.56.0-beta.jar!/:0.56.0-beta]
        at de.pfiva.speech.text.client.service.GoogleCloudService.getSpeechToText(GoogleCloudService.java:27) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at de.pfiva.speech.text.client.SpeechTextClientController.getspeechToText(SpeechTextClientController.java:47) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar!/:8.5.31]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

Answer (score 3):

Netty itself does not support its native libraries on arm platform. This is why you get the error. You will need to not use the native SSL lib provided by netty-tcnative.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm not a Java expert, could you suggest any other library to use? In my case I'm using the google client library and I'm receiving the same error on raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the issue, let's install the openjdk-9-jdk-headless pkg and it solved my issue.

I hope that this was helpful for u all.
Cheers.
OaicStef