# How to fix netty dependency when executing a java jar containing google-cloud app in raspbian

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, netty, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have a java application in which I am using google cloud speech recognition. Everything works fine when I execute the runnable jar in Ubuntu, but when I execute the runnable jar in my raspberry pi 3 with OS Raspbian using the command `java -jar JarFile.jar` I get an error about a dependency with netty, which I have never used.

I have read this question 
[Failed to load libraries: [netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32, netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora, netty_tcnative_arm_32, netty_tcnative]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134054/failed-to-load-libraries-netty-tcnative-linux-arm-32-netty-tcnative-linux-arm)
which is exactly the same as mine, but I don't know how to carry out the answer provided there. If someone could give me more information about how to do that I would be very pleased.

I have already tried:

- Using netty in my maven dependencies although I don't need it.
- Installing tomcat apache (I thought it could provide some SSL solution)
- Adding latest netty .jar to my dependencies

These are the first lines of the error trace I get:

```
dic 30, 2018 11: 14: 39 PM io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts defaultSslProvider
INFORMACIÓN: netty - tcnative unavailable(this may be normal)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32, netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora, netty_tcnative_arm_32, netty_tcnative]
at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java: 93)
at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty does not provide a netty-tcnative artifact for arm32 so you will need to either build it yourself or use another SSL implementation together with grpc. As far as I know they also support using the one which is provided as part of the JDK or allow to use conscrypt.